# How to change state of key inside state object in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following state in a `React.Component` class:

```
this.state = {
  stuff: {
    stuffData: [],
    loading: true,
  },
  moreStuff: {
  ...
  }
}
```

Inside a function, after a button click I want to update the state of `stuff` to `loading`.

It works if I do it the following way:

```
const { stuff } = this.state;
const newStuff = stuff;
newStuff.loading = true;
this.setState({ stuff: newStuff };
```

But I wanted to do it like this (don't get expected result):

```
const { stuff } = this.state;
this.setState({ stuff: {loading: true, ...stuff } });
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You are overriding the value of loading by using spread operator. I also think, first approach is pretty fine

Comment: You've done it the other way round. Should be `{ ...stuff, loading: true }`, which is the same as `Object.assign(stuff, { loading: true })`. `stuff` is the base object and you are overwriting the loading variable.

Comment: @Santa'sLittleHelper it's not the same since `Object.assign` will mutate `stuff`, while spreading won't mutate `stuff`.

Comment: @EmileBergeron You are correct. My mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first copy your object and then change the value you want to change.

```
const { stuff } = this.state;
this.setState({ 
   stuff: {
       ...stuff, 
       loading: true 
   } 
});
```

Because 
if `rest = {a:2, b:3}`

- `{a: 1, ...rest}` will give you `{a:2, b:3}`
- `{...rest, a: 1}` will give you `{a:1, b:3}`